# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this error and i don't quite understand it. Here is my code.

```
export default function Main() {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  function getData() {
    var ref = db.collection("posts");
    var q = ref.get().then((ss) => {
      ss.forEach((doc) => {
        setDates([...dates, doc.data().born]);
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Working</h1>
      <button onClick={getData}>Click me!!!</button>
      {dates.map((value, index) => {
        return <p key={index}> {{ value }} </p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't understand why it is reading value as an object since when I am adding to the array 'dates' I am adding a number. So it should just be an array of numbers. I am really confused I'm not all that similar with the spread operator. For example if I were to `console.log(doc.data().born)` it would give a number like `2001`. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It's a typo, you should have `{ value }`, not `{{ value }}`. `{ value }` is a JSX expression that inserts `value` in that position. `{{ value }}` is a JSX expression that inserts `{value}` in that position. `{value}` defines an object with a `value` property using shorthand property notation (the long form is `{value: value}`).

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly converting your `value` primitive to an object `({value:'blabla'})` by having that additional `{ }`. That interpolation is used in **Angular (and more)**. In **React**, a JS based code just needs a single `{ }` wrapper so `{ value }` is what you need.

Comment: omg @Lakshya Thakur you are so right I feel dumb as hell